# Sending PUT request to KV Core API in Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, json, api, google-apps-script

I'm trying to set up GAS to send an API call to my CRM. [Here is the link for the API documentation.](https://apidocs.kvcore.com/#bd500709-7787-4edf-82f9-b5c3e6ba290c)

I'm attempting to use the code for sending a text via the API. Below is what they provided. I have changed this code to work with GAS(see further down):

```
var myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
myHeaders.append("Authorization", "Bearer {{api_token}}");

var raw = JSON.stringify({
  "message": ""
});

var requestOptions = {
  method: 'PUT',
  headers: myHeaders,
  body: raw,
  redirect: 'follow'
};

fetch("https://api.kvcore.com/v2/public/contact/{{contact_id}}/text", requestOptions)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(result => console.log(result))
  .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

I adapted the code provided to work with GAS. This is what I'm actually trying to run:

```
function kvCoreStyle(){
  var myHeaders = {
   "Content-Type":"application/json",
   "Authorization":"Bearer {{TOKENID}}"
}

  var raw = {
      "message":"let me know if you get this text"
   }

  var requestOptions = {
   "method":"PUT",
   "headers":myHeaders,
   "body": raw,
   "redirect":"follow"
};
 
  UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.kvcore.com/v2/public/contact/{{ContactID}}/text", requestOptions)
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(result => console.log(result))
    .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
}
```

Unfortunately, I keep getting an error saying "Request body must be a valid JSON string"

I have tried using JSON.stringify() on multiple portions of this and can not get it to work at all. Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: try replacing body with payload [ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetch(String,Object)) also your row does not have any text in the message.

Comment: Thank you! I should have been more specific in asking my question. The first section of code above is just what they provide. The second is the code I'm actually trying to run. I'll try replacing "body" with "payload" now.

Comment: changing "body" to "payload" did not work

Comment: Thank you for replying. I had believed that your showing Javascript worked. But from your reply of `It is still giving me the authorization error. I can't tell if the JS is working properly as the only current error being returned is the authorization error.`, in this case, I cannot know the worked script. By this, I cannot understand your situation. In this case, I have to delete my answer. Because I don't want to confuse other users. This is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for this.